# WSO2 and LDAP end point service

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm currently evaluating WSO2 and if it can fit for my project requirements
I have different mobile applications that will connect to our ESB , all of them will use different LDAP server to authenticate their users against it in order to access the applications, what's the best way to achieve this through WSO2 ESB ,I mean configuring multiple LDAP login services as end point services
I heard terms "user store" and "Identity Server" not sure about them , but I got the feeling that they are used for internal use of WSO2 (Storing users who can access WSO2) not related to what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSO2 Identity server to manage your users. You can use internal (Embedded user store) or External User store such as Active Directory. If you use Identity Server you will be able to inherit its features which you can easily integrate with WSO2 ESB.

These links will be useful for your implementations.

[1] http://wso2.org/project/solutions/identity/3.2.3/docs/user-core/admin_guide.html

[2] http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/06/securing-web-service-integration